# Searching for an implementation for AdOtsu Binarization Method

Tags: image, preprocessor, ocr

I am studying about Binarization Methods for Historical Documents.
I found a theory of **AdOtsu**, but didn't find any code about it.
Who can help me.

About algorithm..
http://ebookbrowsee.net/gdoc.php?id=450483567&url=4734b25ed24c4168aceeee1e05dfbb99&c=450483567

Comment: You need to explain what AdOtsu is. Or you need to provide the link where it is explained. Most of the people won't simply google the terms you provide and write code for you. So it would be nice if you could add more details, please.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK PDF file I found about Adotsu is located at [this link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F220602345_AdOtsu_An_adaptive_and_parameterless_generalization_of_Otsu%27s_method_for_document_image_binarization%2Ffile%2Fd912f5097be6c18809.pdf&ei=LA4DU9yoG4mZiQf37IC4Bg&usg=AFQjCNE1SHE5Qdb3X-tWbk39AB_08nlfCQ&sig2=0Qnc0qM8evfaeaUvkTKcHw&bvm=bv.61535280,d.aGc&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

The brief answer: **No**.

AdOtsu was a term coined by Reza Moghaddam and Mohamed Cheriet for **any** Adaptive Otsu implementation.  They actually created two wildly different AdOtsu  solutions in:

"*A multi-scale framework for adaptive binarization of degraded document images*", 2010.

"*AdOtsu: An adaptive and parameterless generalization of Otsu's method for document image binarization*", 2011.

Not only are there two AdOtsu implementations but, if you read the research papers, there are multiple variations of each implementation.  For example, in the 2010 paper one can easily produce the algorithm they call "AdOtsu".  However, half of the paper goes into setting up a generic Grid-Based Multi-Scale framework... with most of their examples using it with Sauvola, not their new AdOtsu.  The reason for the grid approach is because AdOtsu by itself is **extremely** slow and typical Integral Image techniques cannot be used on it, unlike Sauvola.

All of that said, I plan on releasing their 2010 AdOtsu implementation, hopefully with Grid-Based Multi-Scale support, here: https://github.com/brandonmpetty/Doxa